# Automatic type conversion function call C++

Tags: c++

Is there a way to automatically convert to a certain type:

```
class A
{ public:
  int f();
  float g();
};
r(int x){}
t(float x){}

...

r(A) //automagically call r(A.f())
t(A) //automagically call t(A,t())
```

sort of like when toString is called for Java objects when you print them.

Comment: automagic does not work in c++ :)

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: it's a joke) He wrote automaGically )

Comment: If you want something similar to toString behaviour you can specialize the << (stream) operator

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can provide **cast operators** for `A`.

```
class A
{ 
public:
  int f();
  float g();

  operator int() { return f(); }
  operator float() { return g(); }
};
```

But you then call `r` and `t` on an instance:

```
A a;
r(a);
t(a);
```

Here's the full code: http://ideone.com/Pfa4v